# Shiny R: Filter Dataset by a input variable

Tags: r, shiny

Iam trying to filter my dataset by a value of an input. I created a `shiny::selectInput()` with three values as choice. Nevertheless, no matter what value the Input takes, it seems to be ignored by `dyplr::filter()` but not by `dyplr::select()`. Where is the difference here and what can i do to achive what i want namely that my dataset is correctly filtered by the variable selected in `shiny::selectInput()`

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "var", label = "Select", choices = c("height", "mass", "birth_year")),
    reactableOutput(outputId = "table")
  )

server = function(input, output, session){

  output$table = renderReactable({
  starwars %>%
      select(input$var) %>%
      filter(between(input$var, 50, 100)) %>%
      reactable(data = .)  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You’re a victim of non-standard evaluation. The character returned by `input$var` Is not the same as the symbol required by `select` and `filter`.

Comment: looks quite like this. But what to do?

Comment: `.data[[input$var]]` seems to by the tidy evaluated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidy Evaluation [see Hadley Wickhams declaration](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "var", label = "Select", choices = c("height", "mass", "birth_year")),
    reactableOutput(outputId = "table")
  )

server = function(input, output, session){

  output$table = renderReactable({
  starwars %>%
      select(input$var) %>%
      filter(between(.data[[input$var]], 50, 100)) %>%
      reactable(data = .)  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP?